# Bad interpreter: No such file or directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm working through Michael Hartl's tutorial trying to learn Rails for the first time, and I've run into some issues. I recently reinstalled the whole Rails Installer because I had apparently inadvertently deleted some important files. Now, when I try running a test I get the following error:

```
sh.exe": /c/Program Files (x86)/ruby-1.9.3/bin/bundle: "c:/Program: bad interpre
ter: No such file or directory
```

I checked my PATH and attempted to use the solution outlined here: [Bundle command not found. Bad Interpreter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10575644/bundle-command-not-found-bad-interpreter)
..but putting quotation marks around "C:\Program Files (x86)\ruby-1.9.3\bin" didn't do anything for me.

I ran $ rails -v and got the following output:

```
$ rails -v
←[31mCould not find multi_json-1.3.6 in any of the sources←[0m
←[33mRun `bundle install` to install missing gems.←[0m
```

So then I tried running $bundle install and got the following issue again:

```
Tom@TOM-PC /c/sample_app (updating-users)
$ bundle install
sh.exe": /c/Program Files (x86)/ruby-1.9.3/bin/bundle: "c:/Program: bad interpre
ter: No such file or directory
```

I'd really appreciate any help -- I've spent 5+ hours today trying to get back on track and am still at a loss. Please let me know if I'm missing any pertinent info -- Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You need to open this file `/c/Program Files (x86)/ruby-1.9.3/bin/bundle` and see, what interpreter is specified there. Probably it is something like `/c/Program Files (x86)/ruby-1.9.3/bin/ruby`. You need to write `\` before all spaces in the path (or the part with spaces) or put entire path in the doblequotes:

```
/c/"Program Files (x86)"/ruby-1.9.3/bin/ruby
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Igor -- I just checked /c/Program Files (x86)/ruby-1.9.3/bin and there's actually no bundle file there -- does this mean Ruby wasn't installed correctly/fully? Any suggestions on fixing this?

Comment: No! You have `bundle`! Check it once again! You must edit the first line in the file. But file exists! You see the messages that are created while running the file

Comment: I just took this picture to show the contents of my bin folder (http://imgur.com/VRUt4) -- any idea why it wouldn't be there/what I should do next?

Comment: you are right, I don't see here many files that must be here. what show `which bundle`?

Comment: Well this is weird: $ which bundle
/c/Program Files (x86)/ruby-1.9.3/bin/bundle

Comment: the file exists. can you try to show its first line: `head -1 "/c/Program Files (x86)/ruby-1.9.3/bin/bundle"` ?

Comment: Here's what I got: $ head -1 "/c/Program Files (x86)/ruby-1.9.3/bin/bundle"
#!"c:/Program Files (x86)/ruby-1.9.3/bin/ruby.exe"

Comment: I see the quotes. it is good. It's strange but the two directories `"/c/Program Files (x86)/ruby-1.9.3/"` and `"c:/Program Files (x86)/ruby-1.9.3/bin/"` seems to be different. can you check it with `ls`?

Comment: Tom@TOM-PC /c/sample_app (updating-users)
$ ls "/c/Program Files (x86)/ruby-1.9.3/"
bin  lib

Tom@TOM-PC /c/sample_app (updating-users)
$ ls "c:/Program Files (x86)/ruby-1.9.3/bin/"
bundle       rackup      rake2thor.bat   schema      sequel.bat  thor
foreman      rackup.bat  restclient      schema.bat  taps        thor.bat
foreman.bat  rake2thor   restclient.bat  sequel      taps.bat

Comment: Also I went back and tried to get the first line for the file since the ls showed the bundle under the C: ruby directory and here's what I got as a result -- any suggestions for next steps?  $ head -1 "/c:/Program Files (x86)/ruby-1.9.3/bin/bundle"
head: /c:/Program Files (x86)/ruby-1.9.3/bin/bundle: No such file or directory

Comment: Hello, I am facing a similar issue. The first line of my ruby file is `#!"C:/Program Files/Ruby25-x64/bin/ruby.exe"` and I still get the error: ` bash: /c/Program Files/Ruby25-x64/bin/bundle: "C:/Program: bad interpreter: No such file or directory` I believe that it is not reading beyond the space in "Program Files" although the entire string is in double quotes.