# Bundle command not found Windows x64

Tags: ruby, bundle, windows-7-x64, heroku-toolbelt

I just installed ruby with the Heroku Toolbelt, probem is that when I do `bundle install` it gives me this error:

```
sh.exe": /c/Program Files (x86)/ruby-1.9.3/bin/bundle: "c:/Program: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

Acording to this question [Bundle command not found. Bad Interpreter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10575644/bundle-command-not-found-bad-interpreter/13897538#13897538) I should change the PATH, but I dont know how to do this, I have changed windows PATH enviorment variable, even changed to C:\ruby-1.9.2\bin I get a similar error:

```
sh.exe": /c/ruby-1.9.3/bin/bundle: "c:/Program: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

When I try to reinstall the Toolbelt I change the install direcotry to c:\ but still the wizard install git and ruby folders at Program Files (x86) directory.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You should probably install ruby from rubyinstaller.org. The heroku toolbelt is a pain and it will mangle your environment, but with patience you can set it right again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well I found the solution, so I'm posting here.
Problem seems to be the bundler installation in windows x64 machines, to solve this I did this.

Copy the following directories to C:/

> ```
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Heroku
> ```

> ```
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Git
> ```

> ```
> C:\Program Files (x86)\ruby-1.9.2
> ```

Change windows environment "Path" variable, to do this right click Computer > Properties > Advance Settings > environment variables. Path is under "System Variables" section. Edit them to this:

> C:\Heroku\bin;C:\ruby-1.9.2\bin;C:\git\bin;C:\git\cmd

Go to C:\ruby-1.9.2\bin and open the "bundle" file with note pad (not the bundle.bat), change the first line from
`#!"c:/Program Files (x86)/ruby-1.9.2/bin/ruby.exe"##`
to
`!#!c:/ruby-1.9.2/bin/ruby.exe##`

Now go to C:\Git and change the properties (right click > properties) of the Git Bash direct access, and change the target from
`C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cmd.exe /c ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\sh.exe" --login -i"`
to
`C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cmd.exe /c ""C:\Git\bin\sh.exe" --login -i"`

Hope it helps someone

Answer (score 90):

You probably don't have the Bundler gem installed.

Assuming you have Ruby installed:

`gem install bundler`

should do the trick.

Comment: I do have the Bundler installed, before installing it bundle was not recognized as a command. I think this will be fixed if I change the paths, but don't know how.
I tried on another computer with windows x64 and trhows the same error.

Comment: Thanks! This solved my problem with a different error: `bash: bundle: command not found`

Answer (score 4):

**For Windows users:**

I used gitbash to install bundler.

```
gem install bundler
```

and the bundler was installed successfully.
Even after that i was facing the same issue.

Found out that it was due to some permission issue in my case.

Here is what i did:

1. I fired up a command prompt (**Note:** with administrator privilege )
2. I did **gem install bundler** once again and it installed.
3. Now i could do something like **bundle -v**, It gave me the bundler version currently installed.
4. I tried the same **bundle -v** using **Git Bash** but it still is not working somehow.
5. I restarted my laptop, And surprisingly now it is works.

Hope this is helpful to anyone.

Answer (score 0):

I had these issues, and for me the only problem was the spaces in the file paths. Simply adding 's around the path fixed the problem for me:

'C:\Program Files (x86)\git\bin';'C:\Program Files (x86)\Heroku\ruby-1.9.2\bin'

That's it!