# Why won't my Git Bash access "bundle"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, bash, bundler

I'm running through the Rails tutorial and I'd like to view a "test" through Git Bash since it looks like the test results are formatted more nicely.

However, whenever I try to run "bundle exec ...etc." through Git Bash, I get an error of "bad interpreter: no such file or directory".  Now, I have checked that particular directory and I DO have a bundle.exe (since I recently did "gem bundle install" or "gem install bundle").

Now, to be clear, I can run "bundle exec" / "bundle install" / "bundle anything..." through the Command Prompt on Windows.  It's just that Git Bash doesn't want to do these things.  How could I fix this?

Thank you.

Comment: What does your `$PATH` say?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `$PATH` might have trouble interpreting "`C:\Program Files (x86)\...`", as mentioned in "[Bundle command not found. Bad Interpreter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10575692/6309)".

As illustrated in "[Bundle command not found Windows x64](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13898595/6309)", try installing anything ruby-related in a simpler path (no space, no special character).

Comment: Amazing that in 2013, such fundamental parts of the Windows file system are still broken. :/